# How can I show a dialog that is not affected by page changes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, dialog, flutter-navigation

I'm working on a Flutter app where I have a full-screen dialog that contains an animation. When I navigate from one page to another, the dialog disappears along with the page change. However, I want to keep the dialog visible even when I move to another page.

I'm currently using the showGeneralDialog method with a transparent background, but the dialog still disappears when I change pages. How can I achieve the behavior where the dialog remains visible and unaffected by page changes?

Any help or guidance on how to implement this behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I tried giving the MyApp context to the showDialog().{MyApp is the top most widget}